# JSON Call Back Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I obtain data a JSON url such as this?

http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/770672122/cast.json?apikey=Removed_My_API_Key'

When i copy and paste the data like this

```
var titles = {
    "cast": [{
        "id": "162664630",
            "name": "Sylvester Stallone",
            "characters": ["Barney Ross"]
    }, {
        "id": "162653720",
            "name": "Jason Statham",
            "characters": ["Lee Christmas"]
    }, {
        "id": "162652223",
            "name": "Jet Li",
            "characters": ["Yin Yang"]
    }, {
        "id": "162664307",
            "name": "Dolph Lundgren",
            "characters": ["Gunnar Jensen"]
    }, {
        "id": "162670654",
            "name": "Chuck Norris",
            "characters": ["Booker"]
    }, {
        "id": "326392465",
            "name": "Terry Crews",
            "characters": ["Hale Caesar"]
    }, {
        "id": "770731413",
            "name": "Randy Couture",
            "characters": ["Toll Road"]
    }, {
        "id": "770833479",
            "name": "Liam Hemsworth",
            "characters": ["Billy the Kid"]
    }, {
        "id": "770704326",
            "name": "Scott Adkins",
            "characters": ["Hector"]
    }, {
        "id": "770670020",
            "name": "Nan Yu",
            "characters": ["Maggie"]
    }, {
        "id": "162670708",
            "name": "Jean-Claude Van Damme",
            "characters": ["Jean Vilain"]
    }, {
        "id": "162652509",
            "name": "Bruce Willis",
            "characters": ["Mr. Church"]
    }, {
        "id": "162662233",
            "name": "Arnold Schwarzenegger",
            "characters": ["Trench"]
    }, {
        "id": "489251774",
            "name": "Amanda Ooms",
            "characters": ["Pilar"]
    }, {
        "id": "377608335",
            "name": "Charisma Carpenter",
            "characters": ["Lacy"]
    }, {
        "id": "771417014",
            "name": "Nikolette Noel",
            "characters": ["Sophia"]
    }],
        "links": {
        "rel": "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771238417.json"
    }
},
star,
staring = [];

for (star = 0; star < titles.cast.length; star++) {
    staring.push(titles.cast[star].name + ' as ' + titles.cast[star].characters[0]);
}

document.getElementById('Credits').innerHTML = staring.join(', ');
```

It works using the code above, i am trying to figure out how to get it directly from the URL itself.

I have tried to following method

```
var movieUrl = 'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/770672122/cast.json?apikey=Removed_My_API'

$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: moviesSearchUrl + encodeURI(query),
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: searchCallback
  });
});


function searchCallback(data) {
 var titles = data.cast    
star,
staring = [];

for (star = 0; star < titles.cast.length; star++) {
    staring.push(titles.cast[star].name + ' as ' + titles.cast[star].characters[0]);
}

document.getElementById('Credits').innerHTML = staring.join(', ');}
```

Using this JS Fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/6yYYZ/ , could someone please assist?

Comment: I get `{"error":"Account Inactive"}`

Comment: Are you sure that that API can be used as a JSONP service? *edit* It sure doesn't appear to support JSONP from the documentation. I think the service is intended to be something you use from your *server*, not from a web client.

Comment: @A1rPun i removed my api key, but it outputs the same data as listed at the top. It is a direct copy and paste of all the data

Comment: @A1rPun of course you get since the url get no api key.

Comment: @Pointy according to the api documentation it does http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs/read/JSON

Comment: @Pointy is does work... he just had some jacked-up code. A few tweaks and it works.

Comment: @Craig ah OK I see that now. Well your fiddle has all sorts of errors; you should probably fix those.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev thank you for you demo, i see you edited your coment to remove it, Thank You

Comment: @Pointy mike fixed it on js fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typos aside, the main problem was `titles = data.cast` because later you reference `titles.cast.length`... and since you already set `titles` to the value of `cast`, the `.cast` comes up `null` and then doing `.length` on it errors out.

It works when you just set `titles = data` (same as when you simply copied and pasted the data), because now `.cast` exists. Here is what was in my fiddle (since removed due to apiKey, though I doubt it matters if that was your public key and would be visible on any public web page of yours anyway).

```
var movieUrl = 'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/770672122/cast.json?apikey=Removed_My_API'

$(document).ready(function() {    
    $.ajax({
        url: movieUrl, //this was wrong
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: searchCallback
    });
});


function searchCallback(data) {
    var titles = data, //just set it to data  
        star = 0, //initialize star
        staring = [];

    for (star = 0; star < titles.cast.length; star++) {
        staring.push(titles.cast[star].name + ' as ' + titles.cast[star].characters[0]);
    }

    document.getElementById('Credits').innerHTML = staring.join(', ');
}
```

Comment: Thank You, i don't think having my api out there would have done much harm, but i changed it already just in case. I mainly use it on the back end of my site.

Comment: @Craig nah most will have a public API key that you would have to use for client-side logic anyway... so people can see it. The `secret`, the thing you use on server-side is the big one to keep hidden.

Answer (score 2):

There were alot of errors in your code, i partially fixed it so that you get data back

The most important fix was that the url in your ajax call was wrong, I fixed that.

```
var movieUrl = 'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/770672122/cast.json?apikey=API_KEY'

$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: movieUrl,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: searchCallback
  });
});


function searchCallback(data) {

    console.log(data); // do stuff with your json here

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6yYYZ/5/

Comment: You just published your API key on the internet.  I don't think that's wise.

Comment: It wasn't mine, his was already in the fiddle so that was made public, i shall remove it for now. Thanks for the notice

Comment: Ah OK.  I just don't want people to get in trouble :)

Comment: already pastebin'd, go revisions! (j/k) "OMG, not my rotTom API access! $@#$@#"

Comment: @dandavis they are easy to come by so it was no big deal, however i changed it just in case lol